# How to make cards in array?

Tags: java, arrays, file

```
public void readFile() {
    while (x.hasNext()) {
        try {
            String name = x.next();
            int magic = x.nextInt();
            int cunning = x.nextInt();
            int courage = x.nextInt();
            int wisdom = x.nextInt();
            int temper = x.nextInt();

            Card card = new Card(name, magic, cunning, courage, wisdom, temper);
           for(int i=0;i<cardArray.length;i++){
            cardArray[card];}
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
}
```

I'm just making this code reading attribute from text file. The problem is how to gather all cards in one array? I try but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

I highly advise you to go thorough the basic tutorial. See the [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) section and read it carefully.

You should *assign* the card this way:

```
cardArray[i] = card;
```

Note that you're using the *same* `Card` object in the loop, you'll end up with array full of the *same* card. Is this what you want? If not, you should create a *new* instance on each iteration.

Also please note that it's not a good practice to `catch` an exception and do nothing with it. The least you should do is print it to the console, otherwise you might get silent errors.

More questions you should ask yourself:

- Do you want to declare the variables *inside* the `while` loop?
- Is it worth to make a custom class that wraps `magic`, `wisdom` and all other variables? I think your code will be more modular and readable.

The full tutorial is available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html), it's really worth reading. Give it a try!

Comment: This is incorrect.  Consider that when cardArray starts out empty, the for loop would complete without ever doing anything.

Comment: @phatfingers What do you mean "starts out empty"? Do you know how it's initialized? Having it in the `for` loop is a sign that OP have is as a member variable.

Comment: Yes, you're partly right.  My head was in javascript land for some reason.  However, his goal is clearly to fill cardArray with a set of cards retrieved from x, not populate the last retrieved card from x into every member of the array.